# App is affecting "easy mode" on samsung devices

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, android-launcher

My app is generating a bug on samsung devices with the easy mode. I will copy exactly how was reported.

*"I installed the app yesterday on my S7 and for some reason this download or change the QuickLunch and the easy mode was activated. The only was to re-established this was setting the default configuration in all my apps"*

I tried to reproduce this error using an S7 but nothing happen, is working as expected. I have no clue how to check o where I should start looking.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a error was reported only once: you might hunt a bug you will never be able to fix there. Possibility is high that the user correlates the problem with installing your app ( because it fits timing-wise ) but the reason is something completely different. I would not waste too much time before this error has not reported x>=2 times ..